# Размытый шрифт в Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, frontend, браузер

[image: Сайт после добавления разделов]

[image: Старая версия сайта]

Разрабатываю сайт. Первоначальная версия находится по адресу test.rmcb.ru. Позже дополнил сайт разделами, но первый экран, который вы видите на изображениях - не трогал вообще.

После того как закончил сайт обратил внимание, что шрифт и png с названием компании в центре круга стали размытыми. Данная проблема наблюдается только в Google Chrome и пропадает, если я увеличиваю или уменьшаю масштаб. В firefox и даже yandex browser шрифты нормальные.

Код не выкладываю, так как, и в первом и во втором случае, он одинаковый.

В чем проблема, ведь я не менял код первого экрана?

Comment: по поводу `png` если изображение больше чем указано в `css` то задайте ему нужный размер в редакторе изображений

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте применить такие свойства:

```
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В Хроме есть проблема с шрифтами.Уже давно есть баг репорт. И он даже был исправлен, но снова вернулся. Попробуйте на более старых версиях Хрома. Также попробуйте применить какой-то websafe шрифт